# Programatically add Parameter to HtmlCommandLink using a Phase Listener

Tags: jsf, parameters, commandlink, phaselistener

I need to add a component (**UIParameter**) to a **HtmlCommandLink** component dinamically through a Phase Listener.
What I want to achieve is that every element `<h:link outcome="out">` renders as `<a href="out_url_parsed + ?param=paramvalue">`.Where "param" is my component.

I've tried using this

```
private void addElement(final PhaseEvent event, final Class clazz, final UIComponent component) {
    final FacesContext fcontext = event.getFacesContext();
    UIViewRoot root = fcontext.getViewRoot();
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }

    root.visitTree(new FullVisitContext(fcontext), new VisitCallback() {

        @Override
        public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent target) {
            if (clazz.isInstance(target)) {
                LOGGER.info("Element Found");
                UIParameter parameter = new UIParameter();
                parameter.setValue("willberonadom");
                parameter.setId("sessiontoken");
                target.getChildren().add(parameter);

            }
            return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
        }
    });
}
```

But it's not working. The element is actually found on the tree but the UIParameter does not render.

I've found that the UIViewRoot only has child elements after RENDER_RESPONSE phase. So i think this is why my added element is not rendered at the end of the process.

I'm sure I can add this param editing the views but I don't want to do that since it must be present on all h:link in the application and must be present on any other new added too. So I consider this as a better approach to avoid missing tags

On a similar case I've managed to add input hidden elements to every form on view with this code...

```
HtmlInputHidden hiddenToken = new HtmlInputHidden();
hiddenToken.setId("sessiontoken");
hiddenToken.setValue("willberandom");
hiddenToken.setRendered(true);
root.addComponentResource(event.getFacesContext(), hiddenToken,"form");
```

But it doesn't work on anchor tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes:

1. You want to add a parameter to a [`HtmlCommandLink`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlCommandLink.html) component which represents [`<h:commandLink>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/commandLink.html), but you're giving an example with [`<h:link>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/link.html), which is represented by [`HtmlOutcomeTargetLink`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlOutcomeTargetLink.html). What exactly do you want?
2. A [`PhaseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) on `beforePhase()` of `RENDER_RESPONSE` may be too late on GET requests which would only build the view for the first time *during* render response. At the moment your `PhaseListener` runs, the `UIViewRoot` would have no children at all. You'd better hook on view build time instead. For that, a [`SystemEventListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/SystemEventListener.html) on [`PostAddToViewEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/PostAddToViewEvent.html) is the best suitable.
3. You're setting the parameter name as an `id` instead of `name`. Use `UIParameter#setName()` instead of `UIParameter#setId()`.

Provided that you actually meant to add them to `<h:link>` components, then here's a kickoff example how you can achieve that with a `SystemEventListener`.

```
public class YourSystemEventListener implements SystemEventListener {

    @Override
    public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
        return source instanceof HtmlOutcomeTargetLink;
    }

    @Override
    public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        UIParameter parameter = new UIParameter();
        parameter.setName("sessiontoken");
        parameter.setValue("willberonadom");
        ((UIComponent) event.getSource()).getChildren().add(parameter);
    }

}
```

*(if you actually want to apply them on `<h:commandLink>` as well, just extend the `isListenerForSource()` check with a `|| source instanceof HtmlCommandLink`)*

In order to get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<application>
    <system-event-listener>
        <system-event-listener-class>com.example.YourSystemEventListener</system-event-listener-class>
        <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PostAddToViewEvent</system-event-class>
    </system-event-listener>
</application>
```

Comment: thanks! It worked with points 1 and 3. I have another element wwhich in fact is a HtmlCommandLink type so I was always debugging with a different element and also setting the Name instead of the Id did the work. I will follow the second avice now that it all works :')